# Resize Map Marker Using Maps API XML Example

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have used the [Google Maps PHP/XML](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps) Example to build a map and I want to include custom markers. Currently a marker status changes the marker icon and assigns a label as shown below. However I want to use hi-res markers so I need to resize the icons.

I understand I need to use `new google.maps.Size(X,X);`, but I don't know how to build this into the customLabel variable as the examples I've seen use a different method to show icons.

A nudge in the right direction would be helpful.

```
var customLabel = {
        completed: {
          label: 'C',
          icon: './assets/map/images/icon_green.png' 
        },
        failed: {
          label: 'F'
          icon: './assets/map/images/icon_red.png'
        }

      };
var status = markerElem.getAttribute('status');
              var icon = customLabel[status] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label,
                icon: icon.icon,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
              });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of MarkerOptions interface:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerOptions

You will see that icon property may be a String, Icon or Symbol interfaces. Currently you are setting an icon property as a String value. In order to define size you should assign an Icon object to icon property. The Icon interface is documented in

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Icon

So, you should use something like

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    label: icon.label,
    icon:  {
        url: icon.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(X,X)
    },
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi I came the same conclusion in the end, but thank you for the explanation!